# c# Regex Match Search String Plus Next Word

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'd like to return matches for a given search-string in a string.  Plus the next word after the search-string.

**Phrase to search for:  "foobar foo"**

**Example Input:**

```
foo foobar foo bar1 foobar1
foobar foos bar2 foobar2
foo barfoobar foos bar3 foobar3
```

**Desired Matches:**

```
foobar foo bar1
foobar foos bar2
barfoobar foos bar3
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What didn't work? Can you post your current code and explain where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
\b\w*foobar foo\w*\s+\w+\b
```

Comment: Thanks Omega!  That was precisely what I needed!